# How to display recursive xml tree (expandable) with php/jquery like browsers do?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, recursion, expandable

I have the following complex xml source (example at : http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.xml) if it is viewed within a browser, the parent/child method of being displayed = perfect

this is exactly what I am after. However I need to display it within a webpage recursively using php and be able to retrieve each attribute in a table / tree format that is expandable.

I'm tried jstree to no success, jquery.treetable no success, converting to xslt no success.
I am sure it is my lack of experience with these tools, however there must be a way to manipulate the data and display it in a working expandable tree method like chrome does when viewing the above link.

thanks for your help everyone

-- edit to include some sample code :
after multiple tests and no luck, i've gone back to basics using examples from jstree page, utilising xml sample from above link, I had to remove all code above the first  tag.

then rename all  tags to  to conform to jstree requirements, doing this seems to display the correct tree, but no data.
so I then just inserted after the first 3 records test1 etc test2 / test3 but only the first name along side the arrow is displayed.

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo2").jstree({
        "xml_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "../moo.xml"
            },
            "xsl" : "nest"
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you by chance check out the documentation for [jstree's XML rendering](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data)?

Comment: I did and I'veh and I've had 0 success, I did get the basics of a tree, but it only displayed 7 records out of the 100+ and i've had 0 luck finding any helpful examples online unfortunately

Comment: Please show some code and we can probably see where you went wrong.

Comment: have edited original question to include code example

Comment: I believe the problem is with the xml that is being supplied to me, I will have to re-structure it upon receipt and build it in a fashion that jstree will be happy with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here resulted in the source that was supplying the XML to me.
I could not modify it.

but when i manually edited the file so the header was

and the main node was 
followed by each records node being

it started to work, i now just need to work out how to do that automatically.